# Way to extract positive and negative numbers from one array to another two (positive and negative)

Tags: c#

I'm studying c# and I was wondering if there is any way to extract positive and negative numbers (integers) from one array to others two, one that contains the positive numbers and the other negative ones

I've tried something like

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{     
    int[] num = new int[50];
    Random objeto = new Random();
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Random numbers:");
        num[1] = objeto.Next(-50, 50);
        Console.WriteLine(num[1] + ""); 
    } 

    Console.ReadKey(); here
}
```

I have to create two other arrays

```
 int[] positive_numbers = int new [N]
 int[] negative_numbers = int new [N]
```

And I guess I should create a method, but I do not know how I have to do it.

Comment: Well, you know how to loop, although you should see the problem in the line `num[1] = objeto.Next(-50, 50);`. After that loop, loop again and check each element against 0

Comment: And when you've fixed the fact that you're overwriting `num[1]` each iteration and not creating an array containing the numbers, don't forget that indexing starts at zero so an array of size 50 ends at `num[49]` not `num[50]`

Comment: Is 0 positive or negative?

Comment: @mjwills That's a good question, I guess both or cero positive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var positiveNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n > 0).ToArray();
var negativeNumbers = numbers.Where(n => n < 0).ToArray();
```

Or an alternative approach is to count how many even and odd numbers you have, create two arrays and then populate them. This assumes that you want the arrays to be exactly the correct length.

```
// Variables to store counts of positive and negative numbers
int positiveCount = 0;
int negativeCount = 0;

// Because we'll be building new arrays, we need to track our
// position within them, so we create two variables to do that
int positiveIndex = 0;
int negativeIndex = 0;

// loop through once to count the positive and negative numbers
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        ++positiveCount; // same as positiveCount = positiveCount + 1
    }
    else if (number < 0)
    {
        ++negativeCount;
    }
}

// now we know how many +ve and -ve numbers we have,
// we can create arrays to store them
var positiveNumbers = new int[positiveCount];
var negativeNumbers = new int[negativeCount];

// loop through and populate our new arrays
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        positiveNumbers[positiveIndex++] = number;
        // number++ will return the value of number before it was incremented,
        // so it will first access positiveNumbers[0] and then positiveNumbers[1], etc.
       // each time we enter this code block.
    }
    else if (number < 0)
    {
        negativeNumbers[negativeIndex++] = number;
    }
}
```

An alternative approach to the initial count would be to define both arrays to be the same length as the `numbers` array, and then use `positiveIndex` and `negativeIndex` to determine the maximum populated index in the `positiveNumbers` and `negativeNumbers` arrays. The downside is that it uses a little more memory (but memory is cheap for such a small set), and the upside is that you only have to loop through once so it's more performant.

If your situation allows, it might be easier to use generic lists instead:

```
var positiveNumbers = new List<int>();
var negativeNumbers = new List<int>();

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    if (number > 0)
    {
        positiveNumbers.Add(number);
    }
    else if (number < 0)
    {
        negativeNumbers.Add(number);
    }
}
```

Generic lists are basically fancy wrappers around internal arrays. The list starts out with an array of a relatively small size. As you add items to the list, more arrays are generated to store all of your items. You can see the current overall size of the internal arrays by checking the list's `.Capacity` property. Do not confuse `Capacity` with `Count`. `Count` shows the number of items actually in your list, whereas `Capacity` shows the number of items your list can hold before expanding.

Note that in these answers, zeroes will be excluded since you only asked for positive and negative numbers, and zero is neither. As highlighted by Max Play's comment, you should change `>` to `>=` if you consider zero to be positive.

Comment: I would change > to >= if you consider 0 to be positive, but this is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: That's better, but what will the OP learn if you give them the solution? I'd have rather you just explained what could be done and how/why. Also, the first block of code could have just used two `new int[50]`, it wouldn't have been too bad (the lists also have a lot of empty spaces with the second solution)

Comment: @Mike I've added some more information to help you :)

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto You are right, I'm a newbie I need the how/why. it helps me to understand how to proceed with the code. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll handle 0 as positive, add a method to check for positive.

```
 private static bool isNegtive(int number)
 {
     return number < 0;
 }
```

I'd use list over array for unknown quantities. It'd go something like this:

```
public static void SeparateRandomNumbers()
{
    IList<int> positive_numbers = new List<int>();
    IList<int> negative_numbers = new List<int>();

    Random objeto = new Random();    
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {           
       var number = objeto.Next(-50, 50);    
       if (isNegtive(number))
       {
          negative_numbers.Add(number);
       }
       else
       {
          positive_numbers.Add(number);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can always call myList.ToArray() if needed.